# What is the しき particle?

Tags: meaning

I found this in a text but I don't know its function.

> あれ**しき**で

Comment: Hi - could you please [provide a bit more context](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for this? I can tell you that [しか can be translated as "only", or "just"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_particles#shika) (for example, 「私は少ししか英語を話せません」means "I can only speak a little English"), but I couldn't say what it means in the specific text you're looking at without more information.

Comment: @GoBusto They're asking about しき, not しか.  It would be nice if the OP included some context and checked a dictionary, though.

Comment: @snailplane Whoops, so they are. Serves me right for being so hasty.

Comment: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/94686/meaning/m1u/%E3%81%97%E3%81%8D/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to デジタル大辞泉, this しき is a particle that attaches only あれ, それ and これ. It's used to make light of something, similarly to くらい/など/なぞ.

> #### [しき](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/94686/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%97%E3%81%8D/)
>
> ［副助］（指示代名詞「これ」「それ」「あれ」に付いて）程度を表すが、軽視する気持ちが加わる。たかが…くらい。「これしきの寒さで弱音を吐くな」「あれしきの力では何もできない」

Many examples are listed [here](http://yourei.jp/%E3%81%9D%E3%82%8C%E3%81%97%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AE%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8). This しき is slightly literary, and people more commonly use たったこれだけ, たかがそれだけ, あの程度, etc., in conversation.

Because this "particle" can attach only three words, it may be better to remember あれしき, それしき and これしき as separate words. That's how jisho.org treats these words ([あれしき](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%BD%BC%E5%BC%8F), [それしき](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%9D%E3%82%8C%E5%BC%8F), [これしき](http://jisho.org/word/%E6%AD%A4%E3%82%8C%E5%BC%8F)).